# How to enter the website via the ip address in the mobile application

Tags: arduino, esp32

I'm working with the esp32 which has access to wifi, but I need to pass wifi credentials and I can complete this by connecting to est32 access point and entering the website via ip address, where I can pass wifi credentials. My question is, can I enter this webpage via ip address through my vue application without closing it?
Or maybe anyone had similar problem, and found interesting solution? How to pass wifi credentials to esp32 (it has also bluetooth) with my own vue application?

Comment: No code == off topic for `arduino` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you start building your own provisioning solution note that Espressif has a rather useful WiFi [provisioning](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/provisioning/provisioning.html) [example](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/provisioning/wifi_provisioning.html) using BLE, complete with an Android and iOS app.